# Turning trf7970a BoosterPack into card emulation mode

Tags: nfc, msp430

I use a system including an MSP430G2553 launchpad and a trf7970 BoosterPack to emulate an NFC tag. I work according to lasted example and the xls file that Mr. Josh has posted (reading example) in TI website to configure trf7970a.

My questions is:

Is the only thing difference in configuration for reading mode and card emulating mode in trf7970 in the register configuration?

If I understand it correctly, the modification I should made is in the trf7970a.c file. In the following code, I try to configure a type B tag.

```
void Trf7970InitialSettings(void) {
command[0] = 0x80;

Trf7970DirectCommand(command);

Data1[0] = 0x09;
Data1[1] = 0x01;
Data1[2] = 0x83;
Data1[3] = 0x80;
Trf7970WriteCont(Data1, 4);

#ifdef TRF7970A
command[0] = MODULATOR_CONTROL;
command[1] = 0x01; // ASK 100%, no SYS_CLK output
Trf7970WriteSingle(command, 2);


command[0] = 0x01;
command[1] = 0x25;
Trf7970WriteSingle(command, 2);

command[0] = 0x0B;
command[1] = 0x01;
Trf7970WriteSingle(command, 2);

command[0] = 0x0A;
command[1] = 0x3C;
Trf7970WriteSingle(command, 2);

command[0] = 0x18;
command[1] = 0x07;
Trf7970WriteSingle(command, 2);


//UID
Data1[0] = 0x37;
Data1[1] = 0x80;
Data1[2] = 0x12;
Data1[3] = 0x34;
Data1[4] = 0x56;

Trf7970WriteCont(Data1, 5);
//END UID

command[0] = 0x16;
command[1] = 0x03;
Trf7970WriteSingle(command, 2);

command[0] = 0x02;
command[1] = 0x00;
Trf7970WriteSingle(command, 2);

Data1[0] = 0x00;
Data1[1] = 0x20;
Data1[2] = 0x8F;
Data1[3] = 0x00;
Data1[4] = 0x96;
Data1[5] = 0x97;

Trf7970WriteCont(Data1, 6);

#endif

}
```

Thank you for reading my questions. If you have any ideas, it would be very valuable for me since I am new to this area.

Phu Nguyen.

Comment: Typically these devices are configured through their registers. I'm not familiar with your specific device, but generally you'll communicate with it over a communication interface (SPI, UART) and configure the registers for operation.